# Alternative to static Util Classes and Methods in Java

Tags: java, oop

Say, I wanted to have this method which takes a Set and formats that set into a string according to some logic. Eg.

```
public String formatCustomerSet(final Set<Customer> customers) {
    String result = "";
    for (Customer customer : customers) {
        result += customer.getFirstName() + " : " + customer.getLastName() + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am using this code in several classes. Now, where should I put this? I found that Utility classes should be avoided and should not be used?
https://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2009/06/01/anti-patterns-and-worst-practices-utils-class/

Then, should it be Util class of a specific name like CustomerFormatter which is used, or should we make a OOP class out of it? Which one is recommended and why?

Comment: "I found that Utility classes should be avoided" that's not what the linked article is saying: it is saying specifically that the name "util" in a class is an indicator of not thinking enough about what the methods in that class do (so you haven't thought of a more meaningful name), and that poorly-named utility classes become a dumping ground of miscellaneous unrelated methods.

Comment: The easy thing here would be to make an utility class, i see no reason to make something diferent

Comment: @AndyTurner, is it just about the naming convention? So, if we have static methods in proper named Class which is responsible of doing only one thing, then is it fine?

Comment: If you are using java 8 you can keep it as static method inside interface.

Comment: @hatellla yes. There is no problem with utility classes per se.

Comment: @SujayMohan, what do you mean by interface? Do you mean customer class where it would receive a Set<Customer> class and return a string?

Comment: @AndyTurner, in that case, where should all such classes reside in? I mean package? Should they reside in a helper package or they should reside in a different package?

Comment: @hatellla they live where they need to live. It's hard to say without knowing specifics. Implement it somewhere, then use your IDE to try moving it around, and see where it feels "right".

Comment: In case you need different implementations in different spots, say for example a report with an Address and a Salutation you could have `CustomerMailToPrinter extends Function<Customer,String>` and `CustomerSalutationPrinter extends Function<Customer,String>` which could then be used within a CustomerPrinting (util class), standalone/within the Stream mentioned below.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with the fact that util classes should be avoided. It is perfectly fine to have a class that contains static methods that are purely utilities. Sometimes functions or operations should just be functions or operations. There is not always a need to associate them with some abstract object type or whatever.

However, what I do agree with is that when making util classes, you should strictly define what types of utilities will be provided by the class. If you have a bunch of static methods that are related to doing mathematic operations, you can make a util class `ExtendedMath`. If you are doing a lot of mathematics and  the  class becomes too fat, try to refine it further. Group them by type of mathematics such as `Algebra` and `Vector`.

In the end, it is mostly just trying to use common sense. Does it make sense for a function to be part of an object, or can it just be an arbitrary operation?

In your case, you have to ask yourself the question: "Do I want to create a hard dependency of my code to the `formatCustomerSet` implementation?". If you know 100% for sure that you will always format customer sets in the exact same way, and you will never want different formatters then it might be okay to use a static method. If not, then maybe it's better to put it on a `CustomerSetFormatter` class as a non-static function.

I can't give you a yes or no answer, as you have to weight the pro's and the con's yourself. Just take the following things into account:

- When you are referencing a static method, you are creating a **hard dependency** to that static method. Sometimes this is okay, sometimes it is not. A core principle of software development is **reuse**. Can you reuse the code that calls the static function in other contexts as well? Or is the static function too context-specific?
- Another core principle in programming is **dependency injection**. Lets say you have `Class A` which requires a customer formatter. What you could do, is you can make a `interface CustomerFormatter`. In `Class A` you then define a constructor: `A(CustomerFormatter formatter)`. What this allows you to do, is to reuse  `Class A` while using different `CustomerFormatter` implementations. This greatly increases the reusability of `Class A`. When using static functions, this is no longer possible.
- Common generic operations (such as the functions defined in `Math`, e.g. `min()`, `max()`, `ceil()` or `floor()`) are completely warranted to be static functions. They do one thing that is used commonly, and one thing only. Generally, you can take functions like that as an example of when a static method is perfectly warranted.
- Is your function a **pure function**? This is a function that *always* gives the exact same output, for any unique input. Subsequent calls to the same functions will always yield the same result if the input stays the same. If this is the case, then it can be perfectly fine to make your method static. If this is not the case, and subsequent calls to the same function give different outputs depending on some arbitraty state or calls that were done previously, then you should consider making it non-static. Making static functions that provide different outputs for the same input because they depend on some state, is generally seen as an **anti-pattern**.

I hope this helps you out a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java streams, you can actually get what you want with the following one-liner (assuming there is a good `toString()` in the `Customer` class) :

```
String result = 
    customers.stream().map(Customer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

One good place to put it is maybe inside the `Customer` class itself. But I would start using it and only after gathering some info on the use cases, I would consider refactoring this into an independent class.

*Edit (answer to comment)*: Yes, I would start by making this a static method in the `Customer` class since it really does not use any field in that class.

*Edit 2 (note):* By the way, if you want to use the method in your question, consider using a `StringBuilder` instead of `String`.

Comment: This works assuming that the toString() method is implemented as so: `customer.getFirstName() + " : " + customer.getLastName()`

Comment: @jrook, so according to you should it live inside a Customer Class or another class? If another Class, what kind of class will it be? Also, will it be a static method?

Comment: @RobOhRob yes. Of course one can use `c -> c.getFirstName() + ": " + c.getLastName()`.

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases, it is preferable to add behavior directly to the already existing classes as non-static methods. If you really want to reuse it, is still better to create a new class with the desired behavior but as a regular class, which needs to be instantiated and can be subclassed.

**The downside of utility/static classes:**
The main problem is that a class depending on a static method from a Utility Class has tight coupling

1. Testing is a little difficult: Since you have a hard dependency on the Util Class, you cannot easily provide a mock implementation.
2. Inversion of Control: Dependency injection is not possible when using Utility Classes.
3. Proxying: Many frameworks depend on dynamic proxies for adding additional functionality to class instances, example Logging level, which is not possible with utility classes.
4. Single responsibility: Over time, if you are not very strict, these classes tend to accumulate more and more code, which may be not so related to the original methods. The class would lose its original single responsibility.

Refernce: https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/avoid-utility-classes/